# Add a legend title to the legend box with pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I am using [the awesome `pgfplots` package](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) to draw some plots. I usually use `\addlegendentry` and get a nice default legend box. There are some options for legend box placement and layout (e.g. number of columns).

For some plots I would like to add a title inside the legend box.

Could not find the something about this in [the manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf). Does anyone know what is the way to customize the legend box?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could perhaps use the `\addlegendimage` command, as in [this discussion from the pgfplots-features mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.pgfplots/152).

An example, with a small `\hspace` hack to place the title more centered in the legend box:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east]
   \addlegendimage{empty legend}
   \addplot {sqrt(x)}; 
   \addplot {ln(x)}; 

   \addlegendentry{\hspace{-.6cm}\textbf{A title}}
   \addlegendentry{$\sqrt{x}$}
   \addlegendentry{$\ln{x}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For variety, here's a couple of more manual approaches. In each case the legend and title are separate entities, and the frame drawn afterwards.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(rel axis cs:0.9,0.1)},above left,name=legend,draw=none}]
   \addplot {sqrt(x)}; 
   \addplot {ln(x)}; 

   \addlegendentry{$\sqrt{x}$}
   \addlegendentry{$\ln{x}$}
\end{axis}
   \node [above,font=\bfseries] (legendtitle) at (legend.north) {Legend title};
   \node [fit=(legendtitle)(legend),draw,inner sep=0pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={draw=none,legend to name=leg}]
   \addplot {sqrt(x)}; 
   \addplot {ln(x)}; 

   \addlegendentry{$\sqrt{x}$}
   \addlegendentry{$\ln{x}$}

   % place legend
   \node [above left] (L) at (rel axis cs:0.9,0.1) {\ref{leg}};
   % Add title
   \node [above,font=\bfseries] (LT) at (L.north) {Legend title};
   % if needed, add frame
   \node [fit=(L)(LT),draw,inner sep=0pt] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. If I understood correctly, you need to pair ``\addlegendimage`` with ``addlegendentry`` and insert them in the correct sequence... An ``addlegendtitle`` would be so much more convenient!

Comment: @PatrickT That is true, but no such feature is available at the moment. You could make a feature request at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/?source=navbar